# SQLite Convert String to Date in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, datetime, select

I am having some problem when trying to write an SQLite statement to get the sum of certain column with where clause by today's date:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, (substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2)) AS Date FROM transactionRec 
WHERE type = 'W' AND Date BETWEEN DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '+1 day')
```

I am trying to convert my date column to correct date format before making the comparison. My mock up data as these:

[image]

By right, it should return me the record of last row since it's today's date but somehow, I am getting empty result using the SQL statement above.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since your `Date` column is TEXT try `DATE(Date) BETWEEN ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still returning me empty result

Comment: OK. One more attempt.  `strftime('%d/%m/%Y', Date) BETWEEN ...`

Comment: @PM77-1 I edited my SQL statement as: SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, (substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2)) AS Date FROM transactionRec 
WHERE type = 'W' AND strftime('%d/%m/%Y', Date) BETWEEN DATE(Date) AND DATE('now', '+1 day') but still does not work

Comment: **No**. `AND strftime('%d/%m/%Y', Date) BETWEEN DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '+1 day')` If you paste your sample data as text (not image) I would be able to create a demo.

Comment: Nope, it still does not work. It hanged my SQLite browser database as well. I think SQLite does not support strftime :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60735/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-9-dollars-99-cents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes:

1. I swapped *month* and *day* in the concatenation order
2. Instead of alias `Date` I used `SomeDate`.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, 
       (substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2)) AS SomeDate 
FROM transactionRec 
WHERE type = 'W' AND SomeDate BETWEEN DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '+1 day')
```

Apparently `SQLite` does not have a problem distinguishing between `date` field and `Date()` function, but gets confused when faced with `Date` column alias.

Comment: But do you have any idea how to get previous week, month and year?